# TFS reporting: querying for items with specific iteration path retrieves items that were moved to another iteration

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, reporting

I am working with TFS 2017 update 3 & SSRS, trying to build a simple report to get product backlog items at specific iteration path.
I was double checking the results and found out that some items that were retrieved had the relevant iteration path in the past, but were moved to another iteration since.
looks like I am getting historical data.
I am using tables: DimWorkItem, DimIteration, DimWorkItemCategory, FactWorkItemToCategory.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DimWorkItem.System_Title, DimWorkItem.System_State
  , DimIteration.IterationName, DimWorkItem.System_WorkItemType
  , DimWorkItem.System_Id, DimIteration.IterationPath
FROM DimWorkItem
INNER JOIN DimIteration ON DimWorkItem.IterationSK = DimIteration.IterationSK
INNER JOIN FactWorkItemToCategory ON DimWorkItem.TeamProjectSK = FactWorkItemToCategory.TeamProjectSK
INNER JOIN DimWorkItemCategory ON FactWorkItemToCategory.WorkItemCategorySK = DimWorkItemCategory.WorkItemCategorySK
WHERE (DimIteration.IterationName = 'PI3 S5')AND (DimWorkItem.System_WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item')
```

I have very little experience in TFS reporting, and would be happy to hear your inputs.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-relational-warehouse-database?view=tfs-2018

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for your fast response and link. I reviewed the documentation before creating the report and during the investigation. Now I tried adding the table FactCurrentWorkItem to the report tables, and it solved the issue. The query now returns only work items that are currently assigned to the required iteration path.